# Creating a normal class with injections from Spring

Tags: java, spring

Well, I have a normal class (LovHelper) that is responsible for doing some utils tasks. When i say **normal class** is because LovHelper.java don't have @Component, @Service or @Repository annotation.

Inside of this "normal class" i wanna inject a bean from spring, but the bean is always null. Look my Class LovHelper.java bellow:

```
package br.com.odontonew.helper;  

import java.util.HashMap;  
import java.util.List;  
import java.util.Map;  

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;  
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;  

import br.com.odontonew.bean.Lov;  
import br.com.odontonew.dao.BasicDAO;  

public class LovHelper {  

    @Autowired  
    private BasicDAO dao;  

    private static LovHelper instance;  


    private LovHelper(){  

    }  

    public static LovHelper getInstance(){  
        if (instance == null)  
            instance = new LovHelper();  

        return instance;  
    }  


    public Lov getLovByCodigo(Class lovClass, String codigo){  
        Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();  
        map.put("codigo", codigo);  
        List<Lov> lovs = (List<Lov>)dao.findByQuery("SELECT c FROM "+lovClass.getName()+" c WHERE c.codigo = :codigo", map);  
        if (lovs.size() == 1)  
            return lovs.get(0);  
        else  
            return null;  
    }  


    /*Getters and Setters*/  
    public BasicDAO getDao() {  
        return dao;  
    }  

    public void setDao(BasicDAO dao) {  
        this.dao = dao;  
    }  

}
```

So, in another class i just call: LovHelper.getInstance().getLovByCodigo(param1, param2). But i always get a NullPointerException because the bean "dao" within LovHelper is NULL.

After think a little i decided to change my LovHelper.java (using singleton pattern) to a Bean for Spring inject, then I put @Component annotation and remove all singleton pattern the was developed. 
And in another class i inject "lovHelper" and use like this: lovHelper.getLovByCodigo(param1, param2). This second solution works fine, but the first not.

Finally, my doubt is: Why the original code (as posted) don't works.

Comment: Sometimes Spring needs some help finding classes.  Have you tried annotating BasicDAO with @Repository("basicDAO")?  Then add @Qualifier("basicDAO") on the line right under @Autowired where you try to use BasicDAO.

Comment: Spring can't inject anything into objects it doesn't manage. Is Spring creating instances of `LovHelper` or are you?

Answer (score 4):

Spring will only handle injection dependencies to a class that is constructed by the container. When you call `getInstance()`, you are allocating the object itself... there is no opportunity there for Spring to inject the dependencies that you have `@Autowired`.

Your second solution works because Spring is aware of your `LovHelper` class; it handles constructing it and injecting it into your other class.

If you don't want to mark the class with`@Component`, you can declare the class as a bean directly in your XML configuration. If you don't want to have it be a singleton, you can set it with [prototype scope](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-prototype).

If you really need to manage the class yourself, you could consider looking at [`@Configurable`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-atconfigurable). I believe it is intended to solve this problem but it requires aspects and I have not played with it myself.

Comment: This was my doubt. SO, now i have sure that i need to use @Component annotation to inject another bean in this class. Thanks, this was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Your helper should be context aware, but you can make it static:

```
@Component
public class LovHelper {

    private static LovHelper instance;     

    @PostConstruct
    void init() {
        instance = this;
    } 

    // do stuff
```

In this case static instance will keep reference to Spring aware bean.